# iOS - file does not contain an armv7s slice

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture

I cannot build and test on devices because Xcode gives me this error:

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /.../Classes/AddThis/libAddThis.a for architecture armv7s
```

How do I update this library to support armv7s?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

libAddThis.a needs to be built for the armv7s architecture. If you don't have control over this then you will need to remove armv7s from valid architectures as you did.

Answer (score 19):

Try setting the Build Active Architecture Only to 'YES' in the Project Build settings.

Comment: That didn't work. The only thing that works is setting Valid Architectures to armv7 only. It still runs on the iPhone5. I hope this isn't a problem.

Comment: soleil, that won't cause a problem, you just won't get the added benefits of armv7s. I wouldn't worry

Comment: @MaxGabriel what exactly are the "added benefits"?

Comment: I haven't really looked into it, but this blog post seems to indicate more efficient integer division and floating point arithmetic: http://www.primatelabs.com/blog/2012/09/apple-a6/

Comment: +1 It worked for me.I was having issue to run on the device.Changing the above mentioned setting worked for me.Allen can you let me know what we mean by these option Build Active Architecture.

Answer (score 3):

I did this by changing valid architecture from build setting. 
I am attaching a screenshot for your help.

[image]

Thanks,
Cp

Answer (score 0):

Add `armv7s` to the Valid Architectures setting in the Build Settings for the library's project/target.